# Looping through known properties in an object

Tags: c#, properties

I've got an object containing 30 properties that I know the names of. The properties are called "ValueX" (1-30) where X is a number.

How would I call value1 - value30 in a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will select all of the properties/values into a IEnumerable of an anonymous type that contains name/value pairs for the properties you are interested in.  It makes the assumption that the properties are public and that you are accessing from a method of the object.  If the properties aren't public you'll need to use BindingFlags to indicate that you want nonpublic properties.  If from outside the object, replace `this` with the object of interest.

```
var properties = this.GetType()
                     .GetProperties()
                     .Where( p => p.Name.StartsWith("Value") )
                     .Select( p => new {
                           Name = p.Name,
                           Value = p.GetValue( this, null )
                      });
```

Answer (score 7):

Using reflection.

```
public static string PrintObjectProperties(this object obj)
{
    try
    {
        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        Type t = obj.GetType();

        System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] properties = t.GetProperties();

        sb.AppendFormat("Type: '{0}'", t.Name);

        foreach (var item in properties)
        {
            object objValue = item.GetValue(obj, null);

            sb.AppendFormat("|{0}: '{1}'", item.Name, (objValue == null ? "NULL" : objValue));
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
    catch
    {
        return obj.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You may consider using a collection or a custom indexer, instead.

```
public object this[int index]
{
    get
    {
        ...
    }

    set
    {
         ...
    }
}
```

then you can say;

```
var q = new YourClass();
q[1] = ...
q[2] = ...
...
q[30] = ...
```

Comment: Why the downvote?  His question says "Value1" through "Value30"  this is what custome indexers were MADE for.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with Reflection, getting the PropertyInfo objects for the class and checking the name of them.